# Timer speeding up in java even though it's only created once

Tags: java, swing, timer

I've seen several other answers to this question, but all of those posts seemed to have problems that my code doesn't have. (one had the timer created every time the `paintComponent()` method was called, and the other had a boolean that was always true, so a timer was always created on each loop, I think).

I'm writing basically a version of BrickBreaker. I want the user to have 5 lives before the game resets. I have a method `checkForOutOfBounds()` called by `actionPerformed()` in my timer handler class that decrements the number of lives and returns the ball to its initial position if the ball falls out of the bottom of the screen. For some reason the timer starts speeding up after every call of this method even though, after looking again and again through these methods and the methods they call, I can't find where the timer is affected at all. Below is the relevant code from my project. This is all in the `GameFrame` class, which extends `JFrame`. Thank you!

```
protected int lives = 5;
protected Life Life1, Life2, Life3, Life4, Life5;
protected boolean[] livesBooleanArray;

...

protected class GameCanvas extends JPanel {
    public GameCanvas() {   
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        paddle.draw(g);
        ball.draw(g);
        if (livesBooleanArray[0]) {
            Life1.draw(g);
        }
        if (livesBooleanArray[1]) {
            Life2.draw(g);
        }
        if (livesBooleanArray[2]) {
            Life3.draw(g);
        }
        if (livesBooleanArray[3]) {
            Life4.draw(g);
        }
        if (livesBooleanArray[4]) {
            Life5.draw(g);
        }

    }

}

protected void setUpTimer() {
    timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerHandler());
}

protected class TimerHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("TimerHandler.actionPerformed()");

        ball.t += .1;
        checkForOutOfBounds();
        ball.update();
        paddle.update();
        canvas.repaint();
        System.out.println(ball.t);
    }
}

public void checkForOutOfBounds() {
    if ((ball.y_pos + ball.getHeight()) >= getHeight()) {
        int x = (int)(0.5*getHeight());
        int y = (int)(0.25*getHeight());
        ball.setLocation(x, y);
        updateLives();
    }
    else {}
}

public void updateLives() {
    lives --;
    livesBooleanArray[lives] = false;
    if (lives == 0) {
        resetScreen();
    }
}

public void resetScreen() {
    int x = (int)(0.5*getHeight());
    int y = (int)(0.25*getHeight());
    ball.setLocation(x, y);
    lives =5;
    setUpLives();
    timer.restart();
}
```

`setUpTimer()` is only called when the `GameFrame` is first initialized (in the main method), so it shouldn't be creating a new Timer at any other point.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `setUpTimer` to ensure it's only called once? Have you set a breakpoint inside of `TimerHandler.actionPerformed` and checked that the `e.getSource()` is the same `Timer` each time?

Comment: It still speeds up when I make all the code in actionPerformed() execute only if e.getSource() is the same timer that was originally initialized. I put in a statement that prints the event, and it prints: "java.awt.event.ActionEvent[unknown type,cmd=null,when=1460397513714,modifiers=] on javax.swing.Timer@3192c4d6", each time, which means it's the same Timer right? (the address of the Timer is the same for every run)

Comment: Make sure you're calling super.paintComponent before you perform any custom painting to prevent possible graphical glitches

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).